# unable to use VlookUp on excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to do a vlook up here but unable to do it can some one please help me

Here is a Image on my problem if some one can help me fix this
it will be much appreciated thanks
[EXCEL - IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWrE5.png)

Comment: Please post the actual formula inline as text, not as a picture!

Answer (score 0):

Because of the FALSE parameter in your formula, excel looks for the exact lookup value. When it can't find it, it will return N/A. Just delete FALSE or replace it by TRUE, and the formula will look for the closest value that is smaller than the look-up value. The values in the first column of the look-up range, must be in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have found an incorrect formula. Let's move past that. =IFERROR(INDEX(your_array_guy, MATCH(value_in_question,array_you_look_up,false),2),INDEX(your_array_guy, MATCH(value_in_question,array_you_look_up,true),2)  -----You should trim your cells because your data isn't clean? Maybe provide the formula instead of an image? Asking questions correctly and politely will get you further

Comment: IFERR, should be IFERROR and this will not alter the results of the formula.

Comment: @MarcoVos =index(array,MATCH (lookup value , lookup array , match type) this will work with the =iferror function and change the match type. Or I can give you a vba resolution if you prefer

Comment: I think your missing my point. I am just saying that IFERR is not correct (see your answer) and should be IFERROR. My other point: =iferror(vlookup(value,array,column,false),vlookup(value,array,column,true)) gives the same result as vlookup(value,array,column,true), so why is it better? I do not need a VBA solution, because i am not asking the question.